# Deploy Entity Framework Core 2.0 alongside EF 6?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to deploy / install Entity Framework Core 2.0 alongside traditional Entity Framework 6? Is it fully possible, or possible but with some hang-ups, or not possible? Is this documented somewhere? I think I've seen they said they designed it to be side-by-side, but I'm having a hard time fully confirming this. Thanks.

Comment: I would just like to add: We have a pretty big code base that was based on full EF, and since this time, have totally successfully been making all new repositories, and refactoring old ones when the time allows, based on EFCore, and running that side-by-side with full-framework EF. The great news is: It has worked GREAT and without flaw! Great job EF team! Btw, I'm not trying to address here some of the limits one might encounter, but more: is there ever any dll type conflicts or what not, and the answer is not at all.

Comment: The ability to do this is worth its weight in gold, it allows slow migrations, which are often the only reasonable option. The only pain you frequently may encounter is when calling functions like `ToArrayAsync()`, when the old using statement was declared (`System.Data.Entity`, instead of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`), which effectively tries to run that extension method on the wrong version of EF. That is an annoying problem with a very unclear error message, but that's been the only frequent problem I've had, and it's something you can fix easily enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/side-by-side) says the following:

> It is possible to use EF Core and EF6 in the same application.  EF
>   Core and EF6 have the same type names that differ only by namespace, 
>   so this may complicate code that attempts to use both EF Core  and EF6
>   in the same code file.
>
> If you are porting an existing application that has multiple EF
>   models,  then you can selectively port some of them to EF Core,  and
>   continue using EF6 for the others.

This means of course that you can install both EF6 and EF Core in the same project. I have done this in a few simple cases myself and it was working ok.